# How to redirect from just URL to certain port on wildfly

Tags: java, redirect, port, wildfly, httplistener

I have an applictaion running under my.application.com, which is accessible under my.application.com:8080. Now I want wildfly to redirect the users to my.application.com:8080 when they are accessing my.application.com but don't know how.

I know this is probably a totally noob question, but I already read some examples about https-listener and socket-binding. But I can't seem to figure it out. Can anyone provide me with some help? And maybe some insights how exactly that works?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is the default port number for the webserver?

Answer (score 1):

Wildfly is served by JBoss. Which means you can follow the directions on [this excellent write up](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/RunningJBossOnPort80Or443) on running JBoss on port 80(http) or 443(https). If you are not going to set up a proxy then use TCP port forwarding. To do so, find `$JBOSS_HOME/server/$CONFIG/deploy/jboss-web.deployer/server.xml` and edit the `Connector` entry as follows.

```
<Connector port="8081" ...
              proxyName="www.mycompany.com"
              proxyPort="80"/>
```

This will allow JBoss to run on a higher port but will forward traffic from port 80 to whatever port JBoss is running on. If this application will be alongside another instance of JBoss or Tomcat I would strongly suggest learning how to configure a proxy server, such as Apache or NGINX to direct port traffic.

**PREVIOUS ANSWER**

If you want all ports to be forwarded you can add a [CNAME entry](http://www.networking4all.com/en/support/domain+names/dns/cname-records/) for my.application.com:8080.

The configuration would look something like

```
(Sub)domain                |Type  |Target

my.application.com         |A     |(your ip or hostname)11.22.33.444

my.application.com:8080    |CNAME |my.application.com
```

**RELEVANT LINKS**

[Wildfly Docs](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Interfaces+and+ports) on Interfaces and ports.

Comment: DNS only deals with the domain name. so a cname redirects all ports from one DNS entry to another.

Answer (score 1):

If you want my.application.com you have to set Wildfly to respond on port 80.

A common alternative is to have Apache respond on port 80 and forward the request to Wildfly. Your apache configuration would have a setting like this:

```
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
```

Comment: By adding only above mention snippet will this work?

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this.

If you have root access on the server, you can add a firewall rule that redirects from port 80 to port 8080. Something like this:

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 8080 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```

Alternatively, you can set up a mini-server on port 80, that only sends a "302 redirect" to any connecting client. You can use something as simple as netcat for that:

```
echo "HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Cache-Control: private
Location: http://localhost:8080
Date: Fri, 21 Aug 2015 17:44:30 GMT
Server: GFE/2.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: keep-alive

" | nc -l 80
```

Any client requesting a HTTP page on port 80 will be redirected to port 8080.

There may be other methods too, depending on the server software you're using, and what level of access you have.